# How do you say “praxis” in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word *[praxis](http://enciklopedia-vortaro-de-la-merk-angla.weebly.com/temo-praxis.html)* appears neither in Benson, nor in Wells, nor in Vikivortaro, nor in ReVo. (I tried *prakso* in the online PIV, but got no hit.) So, how would you render *praxis* in Esperanto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m surprised that the word *prakso* doesn’t appear in dictionaries yet. I happen to remember precisely that I heard it for the first time in Zagreb  in 1988, and I’ve heard and used it often ever since. It appears in:

- [wp: Antropologio de religio](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiwqr664Y3SAhXCWSwKHSSbDRQQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Feo.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FAntropologio_de_religio&usg=AFQjCNEwuIYw-uNi-j3lPCPbsn52a7nxsA&sig2=GJQ9gxjDgiAaRFdVeD3bUQ&bvm=bv.146786187,d.bGg)
- [wp: Filokalio](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filokalio)
- [Mia elekto, mia decido](http://www.123ahp.com/OMetodi.aspx?lang=EP)

and several other webpages...

Comment: I've used your answer, with attribution, and link, in my online dictionary, here: http://www.cross-reference-kingdom.com/temo-praxis.html

Comment: Someone downvoted this answer. It’s OK, but, across all SE sites, downvoting without leaving an explanation is considered bad manners. The goal is to have a high-quality site, and if you don’t clarify (your view on) how to improve a contribution, it will never improve.

Answer (score 4):

De [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#praktiko):

> **praktiko** Apliko de la reguloj aŭ principoj de arto aŭ scienco, kontraste kun la teorio *mi finis la universitaton k komencis mian medicinan praktikon*<sup>Z</sup>; *post kelka praktiko oni facile alkutimiĝas al la uzado de «vi»*<sup>Z</sup>; *plej efika prediko estas praktiko; praktiko konvinkis min, ke la lingvo bezonas ian nekapteblan «ion»*<sup>Z</sup>.

Seems this one is correct

Comment: It is preferable to include relevant quotes from the linked page, so the answer will still be useful if the link ever becomes unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

> Praxis = Praxis is the process by which a theory, lesson, or skill is enacted, embodied, or realized. "Praxis" may also refer to the act of engaging, applying, exercising, realizing, or practising ideas. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praxis_(process)

He acted on the theory = Li efektivigis la teorion.

Answer (score 0):

agaĵiro estus la plej simpla respondo